# count from .getCount() and raw query differs - typeorm

Tags: typeorm

```
const generatedBlockCount = await blockRepository.countBy({});  
  

const generatedBlockCount = await blockRepository
  .createQueryBuilder(Block.name)
  .getCount();
```

they both resulted in different values, I found through trial and error that the former method selected distinct rows based on some primary key value ( my table had a combination of PKs). The same is done by the similar `repository.count` method.

Is there a way to specify to get all count(without distinct) using the former approach?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @Shayne , not exactly, but, I got a unintuitive reason that getCount() was only for some sort of pagination, so best not use it, I instead used queryRunners

Comment: I must confess I'm growing dissatisfied with this ORM. There have been multiple situations now where its not clear how to perform certain ops without string interpolation, and string interpolation makes my security brain into a very sad panda. Maybe Djangos god-like ORM has spoiled me :/